# Delete action without scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Status resource (generated by "rails g scaffold Status")

```
resources :statuses
```

Link destroy object

```
 <%= link_to "delete", status, :confirm => "are you sure?", :method => :delete%>
```

layout.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

**Rails 4.0.0**

When I click on this it redirect me to Rails'scaffold page (Statuses' listing). How I could redirect user to homepage, or better, **on previously page**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `statuses_controller.rb` you should have `destroy` action

```
  def destroy
    @status = Status.find(params[:id]) # or find(params[:status_id]) depends on how route is built
    @status.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to statuses_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

change the `redirect_to statuses_url` to `redirect_to :back` it will get you back from where your request started or `redirect_to root_url` for home page.

Comment: I get "undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass" http://cl.ly/image/400E382N2t0o

Comment: status is nil, you have to find Status first, for exemple: `@status = Status.find(params[:id])`